# Is it possible to load and save Docker images directly from Artifactory?

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

I have two environments X and Y which are not connected in any way. Environment Y is air gapped.

There's a release process in place consisting of the following steps:

1. Run `docker pull` for all released Docker images. Images are pulled from Artifactory X.
2. Retag and strip repository prefix from all images.
3. Run `docker save` for all released Docker images. This may result in one or more tar.gz image bundles stored on an external drive.

There's a deployment process in place consisting of the following steps:

1. Run `docker load` for all image bundles on the external drive.
2. Retag all images and add new repository prefix.
3. Run `docker push` for all images. The images are pushed to Artifactory Y.

I am wondering if it is possible to simplify this process by directly fetching a Docker image from Artifactory X and storing it as a file without the need for a Docker daemon, and - again without a Docker daemon - directly uploading a Docker image file to Artifactory Y?

Comment: Looks like you are not touching the image itself, just playing around with the repo address and the tag name. Have you checked the artifactory's documentation https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry ?. There are plenty of features to deal with it. Especially if it is 2 artifactory servers. E.g replication, promotion etc.

Comment: Correct, the images are being exported and imported with a bit of retagging. The two Artifactory instances are not connected so the promotion and replication features provided by Artifactory cannot be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One working solution is to use [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo), a CLI tool for working with remote images registries.

An image in environment X is directly saved to disk with the following command:

```
skopeo copy \
  docker://docker.artifactory-x.example.com/busybox:latest \
  docker-archive:./busybox:latest.tar
```

An image file in environment Y is directly uploaded to Artifactory with the following command:

```
skopeo copy \
  --dest-creds myusername:mypassword \
  docker-archive:./busybox:latest.tar \
  docker://docker.artifactory-y.example.com/busybox:latest
```

The image does not need to be explicitly retagged to change the repository prefix.